# How to unset session without reloading page

Tags: php, ajax

I want to log the user out without reloading the page, just updating some divs. This is what I have but obviously not working. The session unsets only after reloading the page.

```
$.ajax({
        url: "logout.php",
        method: "post",
        data: "account_type=twitter",
        success: function () {

        /*****do something***********/  
    }
});
```

in logout.php

```
<?php
    session_start();

    if(isset($_POST['account_type']) && $_POST['account_type'] == "twitter") {

        unset($_SESSION['twitterId']);
        unset($_SESSION['twitterName']);
        unset($_SESSION['twitterPic']);
        unset($_SESSION['twitterUrl']);
        unset($_SESSION['access_token']);
        unset($_SESSION['token_oauth']);

        header("Location: index.php");
    }
?>
```

some help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: what do you mean (The session unsets only after reloading the page.)?? i think the session is already unset but there is nothing to tell current page you already logged out. is that right??

Comment: Logging out will not change content that is already on the page. you will need to reload the page to show the new content IE the old logged in content will still be shown as it doesn't automatically change because you have logged out using ajax, unless of course you are then reloading all those divs with unlogged content using ajax as well.

Comment: @Anigel you mean if I reload the div containing the condition (if seession is set) dynamically this will work? I'll try it out!

Comment: Basically yes. Until you reload the content it will still always say you are logged in. just logging out will not change any content on the page unless you reload the page or the content you want to update.

Comment: I'll add my comments as an answer then as it may help other people with a similar problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically there is nothing wrong with what you are doing.

The problem is with the expectation that logging out will change content that has already been displayed.

When you are logging the user out via an ajax call, the old logged in content will still be shown on the page until you actually either reload the entire page, or reload the content of the div that is displaying the logged in content.

For instance if you have a box that says `You are logged in`, just logging out via ajax will not change that content until you reload that div using ajax or reload the entire page so the server then tells the page that you are not logged in.

Content that has already been sent to the user will always remain as it was unless you specifically change it using either ajax after logging out or by reloading all the content on the page.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    session_start();

    if(isset($_POST['account_type']) && $_POST['account_type'] == "twitter") {

        session_destroy();

        header("Location: index.php");
    }
?>
```

Comment: Whilst that would destroy the session, it doesn't address the OP's issue which is that even after "logging out" logged in content is still displayed.

Answer (score 0):

The session is being unset by the ajax call but you will need to manipulate the divs accordingly after success logout ajax call like hide the username place a login button or remove any user area....